# How can I have slash before and after the label number in reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, citing

[image]

I can produce the slashes in the citation but have no idea how to produce it in the reference label. The desired reference style is shown in the figure.
Test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myxyz.bib}
@article{xyz,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "3-4",
  year   = 5001, 
}

\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{ieee} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{/}{/}{;}{n}{}{,}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{xyz}

\bibliography{myxyz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems the test code is missing.

Comment: Thanks! It's added now.

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{/#1/}`.

Comment: Thanks! It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of `natbib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf),

> The format of the numerical listing in the reference list may also be
> changed from the default [32] by redefining `\bibnumfmt`, for example
>
> `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}:}`
>
> to achieve **32**: instead.

Hence as indicated in question comment,

```
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{/#1/}
```

works for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! It works.